# Parse JSON value having dynamic keys in column and convert JSON to record column structure in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a problem where one column in the table contains a JSON string. JSON has some column fixed and some columns are dynamically added and their count is also not fixed. I need help for two problems in this:-
- Parse this JSON and extract the value of keys which are available and dynamic.
- Convert the JSON column to record structure, using the pattern and value of the key.

Eg. If below JSON is present in the column

*{"y2019m08w35": 0, "total": 0, "y2019m08w33": 0, "y2019m08": 0, "y2019m08w34": 0}*

then the key is **y2019m08w35, y2019m08w33**, etc. and it could be anything as it consists year month and week combination.
Now let's say I get the value of **y2019m08w33**, then it should go to the record column. Which should be created like below

Year -record column (2019)

Month - record column inside a year(m08)

Week - record column inside months(w33) which will hold the value of **y2019m08w33** which is 0.

See attached screenshot for details.

[Initial Value in Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBHV0.png)

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixNB7.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, name, product_id,
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT year, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(month, weeks)) months
    FROM (
      SELECT year, month, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(week, value)) weeks 
      FROM (
        SELECT
          REGEXP_EXTRACT(kv, r'y(\d{4})') year, 
          REGEXP_EXTRACT(kv, r'm(\d{2})') month, 
          IFNULL(REGEXP_EXTRACT(kv, r'w\d{2}'), 'w0') week,
          REGEXP_EXTRACT(kv, r': (\d*)') value
        FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(json, r'"y\d{4}m\d{2}(?:w\d{2})?": \d*')) kv
      )
      GROUP BY year, month
    )
    GROUP BY year
  ) AS json
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

You can tets, play with above using sample data from  your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 2 id, 'Test2' name, 1234 product_id, '{"y2019m08w35": 0, "total": 0, "y2019m08w33": 0, "y2019m08": 0, "y2019m08w34": 0}' json UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 id, 'Test' name, 8338 product_id, '{"y2018m08w35": 10,"y2019m08w35": 10, "y2019m08w33": 20, "y2019m08": 0, "y2019m09w34": 30, "y2019m10w34": 30, "y2019m10w35": 40}' json
)
SELECT id, name, product_id,
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT year, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(month, weeks)) months
    FROM (
      SELECT year, month, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(week, value)) weeks 
      FROM (
        SELECT
          REGEXP_EXTRACT(kv, r'y(\d{4})') year, 
          REGEXP_EXTRACT(kv, r'm(\d{2})') month, 
          IFNULL(REGEXP_EXTRACT(kv, r'w\d{2}'), 'w0') week,
          REGEXP_EXTRACT(kv, r': (\d*)') value
        FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(json, r'"y\d{4}m\d{2}(?:w\d{2})?": \d*')) kv
      )
      GROUP BY year, month
    )
    GROUP BY year
  ) AS json
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

[image]

Hope you can adjust above to whatever naming you really need - note: the naming of output columns in your example is not doable unless you did mockup in Excel or Sheets where you obviously free to name stuff as you wish :o)

Comment: Thank you @Mikhail Berlyant, this is just what I wanted.

Comment: sure. please consider also voting up - this is equally important on SO :o)

Comment: By voting, you mean accepting the answer or something else? I will do that.